Getting error "Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher." in a type definition file
Questions for this error message have been asked many times, but they are always about private identifiers in the actual code. I get this error for certain node modules type definitions which contain a line #private;, if there's at least one private field in that class.

Besides the fact that this syntax makes no sense to me, I wonder why it is marked as error, given that I have the following tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "Node16",
        "moduleResolution": "Node16",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": [
        "tool/*.ts",
        "tool/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "build/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "tests"
    ],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true
    },
}

Lib check is skipped, "node_modules" is excluded and the target and module resolution are set correctly. What else could be wrong here?
A follow up thought I have: What is this line meant to be? Why does it exist at all (or why did tsc add it to the generated .d.ts file)?
Additional information:
Node version: 22.5.1
TS version: 5.2.2

This playground example shows the generation of that "#private;" entry.
I also opened an issue in the TS repository, as I begin to think this might be a bug, either in TS or in VS Code.

What is the node version?

In order to reproduce, can you share the packages creating the issue? Any other samples that might help reproduce. Or it is your transpailed code that have the issue?

The playground link is not enough? You can try my antlr4ng project, which is set up to generate the production build using tsc (for typings) and esbuild (for the bundle), but I think it doesn't matter which project is used. Just run "tsc" in the root of the project and open any of the .d.ts files in VS Code.

It didn't work since there's the need to export, so something will be in the d.ts, but managed. The thing is that no error. Same node version, same code, same tsconfig. What about your package.json?

Thanks for looking into that problem. I'm not sure what else you need. Is the included tsconfig not enough? btw. it seems to boil down to a configuration problem with VS Code. In the linke TS issue there's a hint about that.

It's supposed to be enough, but I get no error in VS Code with the exact same configs, versions etc. My guess is it comes from TS extension in VS Code and not from TS, and the config path of the extension is different from the tsconfig you use.

Yes, that's what I assume too. Just need to figure out what's wrong in my setup.
